# Automatically merge merge-commits to parallel branches on remote

Tags: git, github, githooks, git-remote

I have a master branch with feature `A` and `B`, and I recently created a new version of `B`, called `B'`. The code for `B` and `B'` cannot exist on the same branch since the contents are different but still need to retain the existing filenames. Since `B` is still supported and in use, I cannot entirely deprecate it either. Eventually, the goal is to migrate all users from `B` to `B'`, but that will take a considerable amount of time. Hence, my team is strongly considering maintaining two separate "master" branches -- `(A & B)` and `(A & B')`.

The problem is that since there are two branches, whenever maintenance fix is made to A, I'd need to make two separate pull requests, which can quickly become cumbersome. Is there a way to create a remote-side hook that listens to merge commits in one branch (i.e. whenever a PR related to feature A is merged) and automatically propagate that merge to the other branch?

I am just starting to explore options, so other scalable ideas are welcomed. If anyone could point me to useful resource, that would be much appreciated too. Thanks.

Comment: Long-lived parallel branches like these are a nightmare to maintain. Perhaps you can give us some more detail about B and B' and we can suggest a better strategy?

Comment: If the content is going to be the same, you might so tricks with `git reset --soft` so you don't have to play games to get them to have the same content.

Comment: @Schwern there's essentially a lot of overlap between B and B' and most of the code is either deleted/changed. We could have done something like `if version1 use B else B'` but that would cause a tremendous bloat in our codebase, and it is important that we minimize the num of files as well (so duplicating classes isn't an option). We are pretty invested in the development stage so code changes at this point isn't a viable option

Comment: @eftshift0 that could be helpful for local development but I'd still have to create two separate PRs

Comment: @zeng I agree, a bunch of if statements is wrong, as is duplicating the classes. But this certainly sounds like a job better solved by subclassing, composition, and configuration. I think a separate question with more detail about the problem might get you a better solution. And why do you need to keep the number of files down? That's a strange requirement.